# AWS Cognito: Is there a way to check if user is logged in using HTTP API without exposing user data?

Tags: amazon-cognito

My project is serverless, the user will log in using the hosted sign in UI from cognito, we are only using the `implicit grant` in our oauth flow, the ui redirects the browser after login being successful but i am concerned about the user's data for being potentially leaked, i know the redirection hash does not contain a refresh token but still there could be a chance that within the token's lifespan it could be expose somehow.

so i was wondering if there is a way to verify with a simple true or false if the user is still logged in with cognito.. we are not making use of any `SDK` and we don't intend to use them.

if that is not possible then is it possible to change the response scope for `/userInfo` response to only show few fields?.. to show only `email` and `password`

Answer (score 0):

In the end i did not work with `implicit grant` oath flow for my project, i am now using `ELB` for handling the cognito's session in the back-end and keep the data only for the server side.

So basically i have a rule in `ELB` for my project that triggers authentication when a path is accesed, the console for `ELB` makes it easy to configure and it creates a client session cookie when the authentication is success, this way the `Load Balancer` can have an easy track of the client that is making the request to a protected route by cognito. Once the authentication is success the `Load Balancer` sends the authentication data as request headers to the server and from there it is easy to validate and decode the required user data.